# RVM can't set ruby as default

Tags: rvm

I have no idea why but RVM can't seem to change the default Ruby. I'm using Oh My Zsh and tried *everything* I've found but nothing seems to work.

```
➜  Sites  rvm use 2.0.0 --default
Using /Users/anahkiasen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247
➜  Sites  rvm list
rvm rubies

=* ruby-2.0.0-p247 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default

➜  Sites  rvm reload && rvm list
RVM reloaded!

rvm rubies

 * ruby-2.0.0-p247 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default
```

Now the Ruby is set as default but RVM doesn't load it as "current", which means it does not load the gemsets that are affiliated to it.

```
➜  Sites  rvm use 2.0.0
Using /Users/anahkiasen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247
➜  Sites  gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

backports (3.3.3)
bson (1.9.1)
bson_ext (1.9.1)
bundler (1.3.5)
bundler-unload (1.0.1)
eventmachine (1.0.3)
genghisapp (2.3.7)
json (1.8.0)
mongo (1.9.0)
mustache (0.99.4)
rack (1.5.2)
rack-protection (1.5.0)
rack-test (0.6.2)
rake (10.1.0)
rubygems-bundler (1.2.2)
rvm (1.11.3.8)
sass (3.2.10)
sass-globbing (1.1.0)
sinatra (1.4.3)
sinatra-contrib (1.4.0)
sinatra-mustache (0.1.0)
tilt (1.4.1)
vegas (0.1.11)
➜  Sites  rvm reload && gem list
RVM reloaded!

*** LOCAL GEMS *** 

Nothing.
```

I have no `.bashrc` nor `.bash_profile`. There is no RVM reference in my `.zprofile` and here is my `.zshrc` :

```
# Path to your oh-my-zsh configuration.
ZSH=$HOME/.oh-my-zsh

# Set name of the theme to load.
ZSH_THEME="robbyrussell"
DEFAULT_USER="anahkiasen"

# Uncomment following line if you want red dots to be displayed while waiting for completion
COMPLETION_WAITING_DOTS="true"

# Which plugins would you like to load? (plugins can be found in ~/.oh-my-zsh/plugins/*)
plugins=(git bower brew composer gem laravel sublime)

## RVM and Rubygems
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"

source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh
```

I've tried swapping the above two lines, tried moving the RVM loading into `.zprofile`, nothing. Everytime I open a new instance of the terminal, the default is gone. 
It loads the correct ruby, meaning if I do `ruby -v` I get the version I want, but for RVM it's not loaded and thus I have none of the gemsets.

I've also tried `rvm --default use 2.0.0`, `rvm use 2.0.0@develop --default` but same result.

I've reinstalled RVM, I've set recursively the permissions of the `.rvm` folder to the current user, nothing.

I'm kind of desperate at that point.

Comment: I don't get it. You reload RVM and your version is still marked as the default.

Comment: No it's marked as current, not as default.

Comment: The star means default. Read the output of `rvm list`.

Comment: Yes my bad, but nonetheless – if it actually is the default, shouldn't it be loaded as current when opening a new session ?

Comment: You said it loads the correct ruby, so is that not correct?

Comment: That's the weird part : it is loaded in the environment but not for RVM, which means it doesn't load the gemsets affiliated to it, will edit the main post with more details.

Comment: are you sure when you reloaded RVM, it didnt just change to the default gemset, and you were working in a different gemset?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34762/discussion-between-maxime-fabre-and-sevenseacat)

Answer (score 6):

As you are using OH-MY-ZSH you might be hitting issue similar to this: https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/pull/1359

RVM has a "fix" function, run:

```
rvm get head --auto-dotfiles
```

It will reorganize your dot files - it is important to read the output and follow instructions.

Make sure to use login shell for best effect.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't change anything, it replaced the lines in the correct dotfiles but the bug persists.

Comment: did you get info about forced `PATH` and follow instructions to remove it?

Comment: My ruby version changes back to system installed old ruby when I run `source ~/.zshrc`. I fix it by commenting out the PATH setting line in .zshrc as the pull request suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Ah ha !! I just faced the same problem and resolved it eventually.

Let me reiterate my issue: Everytime i start my terminal, i had to first do a bundle install each time. Then i figured, Its not correct. So i tried sourcing my zshrc.

So everytime i had to do `source ~/.zshrc` or simply `zsh` also did the same and my gemset would get identified. Ofcourse **assuming RVM and all other dependencies are installed correctly**

Finally i figured i needed to do the following:

- `$ vim ~/.zlogin`
- The contents of the .zlogin should be

  ```
  [[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
  zsh   #to initiate zsh (you could also replace this with 'source ~/.zshrc')
  ```

This resolved my problem. Now everytime i start my terminal, my defaults are all set.

*Let me know if this works for you.*