# RVM: Use Ruby everytime?

Tags: ruby, rvm

I have installed Ruby 2.1.2 using RVM on Ubuntu 14.04. It works the first time, but then I restarted the terminal and it didn't work anymore. I figured out that I had to type `rvm use ruby-2.1.2` every time.

I have researched and found out that I had to set a default. I did that, but it stil doesn't work. I also checked that the .bash_profile and .profile files look right.

Can anyone help me with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out myself and now post this for future reference:

I had to check the setting 'use as login shell' in the gnome terminal. See "[RVM can't set ruby as default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18032970/rvm-cant-set-ruby-as-default)" for reference.

Comment: It's adviced in the installation instructions for RVM.